# Position:fixed issue in IO S safari

Tags: html, ios, css, safari

i am using position:fixed for the  menu and sub menus , main menu is working fine in all the browsers even in safari but problem coming with sub menu i have fixed my menu at the top of the window with 100% width, for sub menu also i have given position fixed so that i will also take the full width of the window, this is coming fine in all browsers, but in safari the sub menu is getting start from its parent element and its not taking the full width of the window.

here is the code for sub menu dropdown

```
 .dropdown-menu {
          position: fixed;
          top: 55px;
          left: 0;
          z-index: 1000;
          display: none;
          float: left;
          min-width: 100%;
          padding: 5px 0;
          margin: 2px 0 0;
          font-size: 14px;
         list-style: none;
         background-color: #ffffff;
         background-clip: padding-box;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make dropdown's parent 'li' to position static. e.g

```
.nav > li
{
  position:static;
}
```

that will work.